ros2_control publishing NaN to /diff_controller/odom
Im trying to launch my Gazebo simulation of my 4-wheeled robot using the following launch file, but when I inspect everything, I see that the odometry is not being calculated correctly. What is going wrong here?
Launch File:
from ament_index_python import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, DeclareLaunchArgument, RegisterEventHandler
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit

import os
import xacro

def generate_launch_description():
    package_name = 'pieperkieker_description'
    pkg_share = get_package_share_directory(package_name)

    xacro_filename = 'pieperkieker.urdf.xacro'
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_share,'xacro',xacro_filename)
    robot_description = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)

    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='true')
    gazebo_params_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name), "config/gazebo_params.yaml")
    my_controllers_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name), "config/my_controllers.yaml")

    robot_state_publisher_node = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'true', 'use_ros2_control': 'true'}.items()
    )

    # Launching Gazebo
    gazebo_node = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
        os.path.join(get_package_share_directory("gazebo_ros"),
                     "launch/gazebo.launch.py")
    ]),
        launch_arguments={'pause': 'false', 'extra_gazebo_args': '--ros-args --params-file ' + gazebo_params_file}.items()
    )
    
    gazebo_spawner = Node(
        package='gazebo_ros',
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        output='screen',
        arguments=["-topic", "/robot_description", "-entity", "pieperkieker", '-z', LaunchConfiguration('z_pos')]
    )

    differential_controller_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=["diff_controller", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"]
    )

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster"]
    )

    delay_robot_controller_spawner_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            on_exit=[differential_controller_spawner],
        )
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('z_pos', default_value='1.6'),
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        gazebo_node,
        gazebo_spawner,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,     delay_robot_controller_spawner_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
    ]) 

my_controller.yaml:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 30
    use_sim_time: false

    diff_controller:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController
    
    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

diff_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    left_wheel_names: ['Left_motor_wheel_joint']
    right_wheel_names: ['Right_motor_wheel_joint']
    
    wheel_seperation: 1.5
    wheel_radius: 0.30

    publish_rate: 50.0
    odom_frame_id: odom
    base_frame_id: base_link
    pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001]
    twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001]


    position_feedback: true
    open_loop: false
    enable_odom_tf: true 
    use_stamped_vel: false
    publish_limited_velocity: true
    publish_cmd: true

ros2 topic echo /diff_controller/odom:
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 6
    nanosec: 31000000
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: .nan
      y: .nan
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: .nan
      y: .nan
      z: .nan
      w: .nan 
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.0006918142581881663
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: .nan

when running Rviz2:
Error:   TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_link" from authority "Authority undetectable" because of a nan value in the transform (-nan -nan 0.000000) (-nan -nan -nan -nan) at line 235 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp
Error:   TF_DENORMALIZED_QUATERNION: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_link" from authority "Authority undetectable" because of an invalid quaternion in the transform (-nan -nan -nan -nan) at line 254 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp

EDIT:
ros2_control tag:
<ros2_control name="GazeboSystem" type="system">
            <hardware>
                <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
            </hardware>
            
            <joint name="Left_motor_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-15.0</param>
                    <param name="max">15.0</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
                <state_interface name="effort"/>
            </joint>

            <joint name="Right_motor_wheel_joint">
                <command_interface name="velocity">
                    <param name="min">-15.0</param>
                    <param name="max">15.0</param>
                </command_interface>
                <state_interface name="velocity"/>
                <state_interface name="position"/>
                <state_interface name="effort"/>
            </joint>
        </ros2_control>

snippet of echo from /joint_states:
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 6
    nanosec: 728000000
  frame_id: ''
name:
- Left_motor_wheel_joint
- Right_motor_wheel_joint
position:
- 0.022332387535943354
- 0.028809918416706104
velocity:
- 0.011844706014012498
- 0.01134521691053945
effort:
- .nan
- .nan

EDIT:
urdf:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="pieperkieker">  

    <!-- BASE LINK -->
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/base_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="light_taupe"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/base_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-0.047144 -0.0028345 -0.41478" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="1.59" />
            <inertia ixx="20.641" ixy="0.00016992" ixz="-0.49423" iyy="6.5187" iyz="0.00055771" izz="24.879" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- LEFT MOTOR WHEEL LINK -->
    <joint name="Left_motor_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.77784 0.723 -1.3493" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="Left_motor_wheel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Left_motor_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Left_motor_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="ash_gray"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Left_motor_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-1.75365585441956E-07 0.0270006737216059 -1.93349436128365E-07" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="2.81598571989199" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0184877495766498" ixy="2.29761900848141E-07" ixz="-2.57088871335598E-08" iyy="0.0301863785104543" iyz="1.93292070690171E-07" izz="0.0184876895395364" />
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="Left_motor_wheel_link">
        <mu1 value="1.0"/>
        <mu2 value="0.25"/>
        <kp value="10000000.0" />
        <kd value="1.0" />
        <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
        <minDepth>0.005</minDepth>
        <gravity>true</gravity>
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <!-- LEFT SWIVEL LINK -->
    <joint name="Left_swivel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="0.96561 0.75 -1.084" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="Left_swivel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Left_swivel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Left_swivel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pale_gray"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Left_swivel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-0.0618449265724237 1.49015045774082E-09 -0.158180113097024" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="3.7827012394741" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0393150604894362" ixy="1.81657492835183E-10" ixz="-0.0153011144840003" iyy="0.0361500925653868" iyz="-4.69410806455382E-10" izz="0.0278648244978593" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- LEFT SWIVEL WHEEL LINK -->
    <joint name="Left_swivel_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.15614 -0.017798 -0.28963" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="Left_swivel_link" />
        <child link="Left_swivel_wheel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Left_swivel_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Left_swivel_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pale_blue"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Left_swivel_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-8.42359524355629E-08 0.0177982203392603 -1.46493464531217E-06" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="1.01679969602072" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0140382716247924" ixy="2.15723669563332E-08" ixz="9.27403982855476E-19" iyy="0.0261356546025606" iyz="6.87396277095084E-09" izz="0.0140382716247924" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="Left_swivel_wheel_link">
        <mu1 value="1.0"/>
        <mu2 value="0.25"/>
        <kp value="10000000.0" />
        <kd value="1.0" />
        <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
        <minDepth>0.005</minDepth>
        <!-- <material>Gazebo/Grey</material> -->
    </gazebo>

    <!-- RIGHT MOTOR WHEEL LINK -->
    <joint name="Right_motor_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.77784 -0.72355 -1.3493" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="Right_motor_wheel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Right_motor_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Right_motor_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="ash_gray"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Right_motor_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-1.75365585441956E-07 -0.0270006737216059 -1.93349436128365E-07" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="2.81598571989199" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0184877495766498" ixy="2.29761900848141E-07" ixz="-2.57088871335598E-08" iyy="0.0301863785104543" iyz="1.93292070690171E-07" izz="0.0184876895395364" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="Right_motor_wheel_link">
        <mu1 value="1.0"/>
        <mu2 value="0.25"/>
        <kp value="10000000.0" />
        <kd value="1.0" />
        <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
        <minDepth>0.005</minDepth>
        <gravity>true</gravity>
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <!-- RIGHT SWIVEL LINK -->
    <joint name="Right_swivel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="0.96561 -0.75 -1.084" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="Right_swivel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Right_swivel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Right_swivel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pale_gray"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Right_swivel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-0.0618449235933072 -1.4860177088849E-08 -0.158180125308815" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="3.78270123947423" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0393150604894546" ixy="1.81658250750189E-10" ixz="-0.015301114483994" iyy="0.0361500925653877" iyz="-4.6940988688316E-10" izz="0.0278648244978431" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- RIGHT SWIVEL WHEEL LINK -->
    <joint name="Right_swivel_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.15614 0.017798 -0.28963" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="Right_swivel_link" />
        <child link="Right_swivel_wheel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Right_swivel_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Right_swivel_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pale_blue"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/Right_swivel_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="1.17173987068675E-06 -0.0177982367124008 -8.99404833498707E-07" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="1.01679969602083" />`
            <inertia ixx="0.0140382716247939" ixy="1.96477435121725E-09" ixz="-8.49248892198181E-19" iyy="0.0261356546025633" iyz="2.25556660675932E-08" izz="0.0140382716247939" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="Right_swivel_wheel_link">
        <mu1 value="1.0"/>
        <mu2 value="0.25"/>
        <kp value="10000000.0" />
        <kd value="1.0" />
        <fdir1 value="1 0 0"/>
        <minDepth>0.005</minDepth>
        <!-- <material>Gazebo/Grey</material> -->
    </gazebo>

    <!-- LIDAR LINK -->
    <joint name="LIDAR_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0.82361 -0.0005 -0.54721" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="LIDAR_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint>  

    <link name="LIDAR_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/LIDAR_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="light_gray"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/LIDAR_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin
                xyz="-0.0582313935385681 0.000407692765196366 -0.00371697005238841"
                rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass
                value="0.629336184485877" />
            <inertia
                ixx="0.000461493681982852"
                ixy="1.67552777937339E-06"
                ixz="2.29569144720043E-09"
                iyy="0.000858189733433334"
                iyz="-1.32457825126373E-07"
                izz="0.00095321317936619" />
            </inertial>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="LIDAR_link">
    <sensor type="gpu_ray" name="head_hokuyo_sensor">
      <!-- <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose> -->
      <visualize>false</visualize>
      <update_rate>40</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>720</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
            <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.10</min>
          <max>30.0</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <!-- Noise parameters based on published spec for Hokuyo laser
               achieving "+-30mm" accuracy at range < 10m.  A mean of 0.0m and
               stddev of 0.01m will put 99.7% of samples within 0.03m of the true
               reading. -->
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_head_hokuyo_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so">
        <ros>
            <argument>~out:=/scan</argument>
        </ros>
        <topicName>/livox/laser_scan</topicName>
        <output_type>sensor_msgs/LaserScan</output_type>
        <frameName>LIDAR_link</frameName>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- GPS LINK -->
  <joint name="GPS_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0.44944 0 0.25179" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="GPS_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="GPS_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/GPS_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pale_blue"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/GPS_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin
                xyz="-0.0049964 2.2204E-16 -0.13067"
                rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass
                value="0.2965" />
            <inertia
                ixx="0.0050565"
                ixy="-8.4855E-20"
                ixz="-0.00027093"
                iyy="0.0052066"
                iyz="-7.8325E-20"
                izz="0.00045898" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- IMU LINK -->
    <joint name="IMU_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0.3 0 -0.034" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="GPS_link" />
        <child link="imu_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="imu_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/imu_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="dark_gray"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find pieperkieker_description)/meshes/imu_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-0.0951648137554728 0.000109241920836389 -0.10401017479759" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="0.550281605017471" />
            <inertia ixx="0.00172215103688083" ixy="9.85030111532084E-16" ixz="-0.00192275478441672" iyy="0.00443169206796204" iyz="-3.21809766109378E-13" izz="0.00313445739149352" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

</robot>
```


Can you post the content of the /joint_state topic as well as the ros2_control tag of the URDF please?

Hello @ChristophFroehlich I have added what you have asked for :D

Which ROS distro (and ros2_control version) are you using?

I am working on iron and these are my ros2_control and ros2_controller versions:

ros-iron-ros2-control
ros-iron-ros2-controllers
ros-iron-gazebo-ros2-control


These are not the versions but only the apt package names. For example, you can check with ros2 pkg xml ros2_control -t version.

Check, my bad! 3.24.0 is what you are looking for.

I want to disappear into a hole in the ground.
The problem was indeed in the controllers.yaml file and to be specific in this line:
wheel_seperation: 1.5
This should have been:
wheel_sepAration: 1.44655

Thanks for reporting, glad you found it! I'll add a simple check to the parameter to be non-zero. This makes totally sense here..

Just to clarify: wheel_separation: 1.44655, with a lower case "a"...?

Yes it should be wheel_separation with a lowercase "a".

fyi: The parameter wheels_per_side doesn't have any effect and was reduced from iron on (I just saw that there are remnants in the docs, I'll delete it).
However, you set the parameter to 1 but add three joints to left/right_wheel_names?! The wheel_names will be used to read the velocity feedback (with your setup position_feedback: false, open_loop: false) from the respective state interfaces.

I have updated the code above, but I am still encountering the same issues unfortunately. I have also added the xacro/urdf. The robot i am working on has 4 wheels, but only 2 of these are connected to the motors, hence my confusion on this topic.

could you please check your behavior with example_2? If you can't reproduce your issue with diff_bot, try to change the parameters to match your config and see which change is causing your issue.

I have just checked example_2 and this works! Thanks for you help so far. Let the debugging begin!

Just found the problem and posted it as an answer, thanks for your help.
